# I want this modal load 5 second letter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want this modal load 5 second letter. How to set jquery time set.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
        jQuery('#myModal').modal('show');

    });
```

Comment: You could have also type in **google** : `load content 5 second later`
But it's kinda difficult if you write **letter**..

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Flagged for moderator attention: your begging message has been removed once already, and your client's urgency is not our problem. Furthermore, no-one is entitled to priority treatment here, and it is impolite to ask - your question is not more important than anyone else's. If you need a speedy, guaranteed response then consider paying for help on another site (e.g. TopTal or AirPair).

Answer (score 3):

Use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to add a delay to a function/action.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('#myModal').modal('show');
    }, 5000);
});
```